# Custom shortcode breaks my page

Tags: shortcode

Okay so I'm trying to create a wordpress shortcode called chapter, i.e. `[chapter]text[/chapter]`.

What this does is it first checks if the content entered is already in the database, if it's not it will add it to the database and will also add a count to another table. Then it outputs this in a div

This is the code I have

```
function chapters( $atts, $content ) {
    $postid = get_post($my_id);

    $result_chaptertitle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ltd_chapters_titles WHERE chaptertitle='$content' AND postid='$postid'");
    $num_rows_chaptertitle = mysql_num_rows($result_chaptertitle);

    $result_chaptercount = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ltd_chapters WHERE postid='$postid'");
    $num_rows_chaptercount = mysql_num_rows($result_chaptercount);

    if ($num_rows_chaptertitle == 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO ltd_chapters_titles (postid, chaptertitle) VALUES ('$postid','$content')");
    }

    if ($num_rows_chaptercount == 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO ltd_chapters (postid, chapter) VALUES ('$postid', 1)");
    } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE ltd_chapters SET chapter=chapter+1 WHERE postid='$postid'");
    }

    $chaptercount = mysql_query("SELECT chapter FROM table WHERE postid='$postid'");

    mysql_query("UPDATE ltd_chapters SET count='$chaptercount' WHERE postid='$postid' AND chaptertitle='$content'");

    return '<div id="chapter'.$chaptercount.'"><h3>'.$content.'</h3></div>';

}
add_shortcode('chapter', 'chapters');
```

When I apply this in a post, the entire content of the post doesn't show up on the page and everything afterwards isn't rendered as well (so no footer etc.) However the div that the `the_content();` is in is closed of like it should though

Can anyone offer me any insight into what I have been doing wrong? I'm pretty new to PHP

Answer (score 2):

Is the `$my_id` variable supposed to come from an attribute on the shortcode? E.g. `[chapter my_id="123"]Lorum ipsum...[/chapter]`

If so, at the beginning of your `chapters()` function, you need to retrieve the attributes out of the array being passed in. Something like:

```
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'foo' => 'something',
    'bar' => 'something else',
), $atts ) );
```

The values in that array are defaults which can be set if the keys don't exist in your `$attr` (which comes from the shortcode tag in your content).

Otherwise, we need to know more about where `$my_id` is getting set in the first place. If you're just trying to get the post ID of the current post that contains the shortcode, then maybe try this:

```
global $post;
$my_id = $post->ID;
```

Lastly, just as a best-practice, instead of directly calling MySQL functions, you might want to read up on the `$wpdb` interface, and use the core database access functions. It will help your code stay future-proof.

Comment: Hey there, 

I've copy pasted the get_post($my_id); from the WP codex site to get the ID of the post. I thought that this would then store the ID of the post into the $postid variable.

Is that any help?

Comment: Give TheDeadMedic's code a try and see if it works for you. It's what I was suggesting to do.

Answer (score 1):

- No variable `$my_id` on line [3], `$postid` will default to the current post *object*
- Unescaped data in queries, likely to fail
- Use of object `$postid` as string, typically fatal error

I hope the code will speak for itself, but I highly recommend you improve your understanding of both WordPress & PHP - check out the manuals, read blogs, get a book if it suits!

```
function chapters( $atts, $content )
{
    // We need access to some variables outside the function, so globalise them.
    global $wpdb, $post;

    $chapter_title = $wpdb->get_row(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            'SELECT * FROM ltd_chapters_titles WHERE chaptertitle = %s AND postid= %d',
            $content, $post->ID
        )
    );

    if ( ! $chapter_title ) {
        // Make use of all the handy methods $wpdb has to offer!
        $wpdb->insert( 'ltd_chapters_titles',
            array( 'chaptertitle' => $content, 'postid' => $post->ID ),
            array( '%s', '%d' )
        );
    }

    // For sanity to inject straight into string rather than prepare()
    $post_id = absint( $post->ID );

    if ( $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT postid FROM ltd_chapters WHERE postid = $post_id" ) ) {
        $wpdb->query( "UPDATE ltd_chapters SET chapter=chapter+1 WHERE postid = $postid" );
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert( 'ltd_chapters',
            array( 'chapter' => 1, 'postid' => $post->ID ),
            array( '%d', '%d' )
        );
    }

    $chapter = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT chapter FROM ltd_chapters WHERE postid = $post_id" );
    $wpdb->update( 'ltd_chapters',
        array( 'count', $count ),
        array( 'postid' => $post_id ),
        '%s',
        '%d'
    );

    return sprintf( '<div id="chapter%d"<h3>%s</h3></div>', $chapter, $content );
}
```

Have faith, and don't give up!

Comment: That was amazing! After a lot of hard work and with the help of this code I have finally successfully added the feature.

I have just been learning PHP since the past week, this was my first real own project; your code really helped me understand some of the concepts, thanks again